# How can I use Sinatra helpers inside my model?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have some code that I need to access both inside my models as well as inside my views. How can I make a helper method available in both locations?

*(While recognizing that this is generally an antipattern, I have a specific need. The DB stores some special strings for referencing a specific entry across tables. This string may appear both in prose—where I want to convert it into a real model reference in a helper called from the view—as well as in special table lookups—where I need to resolve it in the model.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```ruby
### helpers/my_helper.rb #################################
module MyHelper
  def resolve(path)
    # …helper code here…
  end
  module_method :resolve   # Allows `MyHelper.resolve`
end
```

```ruby
### helpers/init.rb ######################################
require_relative 'my_helper'
MyApp.helpers MyHelper       # Module's methods as helpers
```

```ruby
### models/init.rb #######################################
require_relative '../helpers/my_helper' # *vomit*
require_relative 'my_model'
```

```ruby
### models/my_model.rb ###################################
class MyModel < Sequel::Model
  def reference
    MyHelper.resolve(the_path)
  end
end
```